# Invalid syntax using np.zeros

Tags: python

I would like to write this:

```
x = 'something_{}'.format(1)
exec('{} = {}'.format(x,np.zeros((2,2))))
```

Problem: I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and I don't know how to solve it.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: np.zeros((2,2)) returns an array which you can't use in a `format` call like this.

Comment: Run `"{} = {}".format(x,np.zeros((2,2)))` first to see what its value is. You'll see there's an embedded `\n`, so you'll get an error passing it to `exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

String representation of numpy array is not a valid Python literal, therefore it cannot be `eval`ed.

```
z = np.zeros((2,2))
str(z)  # [[ 0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.]]  <-- invalid literal
```

Technically what you want may be achieved by using repr of object (but in general case it also won't work, e.g. when size of matrix is huge):

```
import numpy as np
x = 'something_{}'.format(1)
exec('{} = np.{!r}'.format(x, np.zeros((2,2))))
```

But what you really want to do is dynamic variable name, and that's a duplicate.